# when a structure has c-tor, why can't I statically initialize it?

Tags: c++, static, constructor, initialization, structure

My question: When a structure has c-tor, why can't I statically initialize it ?

My compiler claims :

```
type `myStruct' must be initialized by constructor, not by `{...}'
```

Why is that ? I'm using gcc version 3.4.4 (cygming special, gdc 0.12, using dmd 0.125)

To illustrate, here is the `struct` that is rejected by the compiler.

```
struct myStruct
{
    int a;
    double b;

    myStruct() { a= 0; b = 0.0; }
}

void main()
{
    myStruct ms = {7, 7.7}; // Now this compiler does not accept.
}
```

Comment: Sample code that costs you hours literally to format, until it gets accepted !! It claims I do not have properly indented code by 4 spaces. I do. I can count to 4.

struct myStruct 
{
    int a;
    double b;

    // Now I add here a default c-tor
    myStruct()
    {
        a= 0;
        b = 0.0;
    }
}

void main()
{
    myStruct ms = {7, 7.7}; // Now this compiler does not accept.
}

Comment: @Peter No need to do that by hand. Paste the code into the editor, select it, hit the button (for Ctrl-K).

Comment: I suppose you are talking about array initialization syntax? Because you can only initialize POD types this way...

Comment: What code do you think you need to see, @Robert? The question seems perfectly clear to me without any code.

Comment: @RobKennedy Peter asked why he was getting a specific error, but I'm assuming he also wants a solution that will give the effect he desires.  For the former, code does not help.  For the latter, code is necessary.

Comment: @delnam Even better, if you're using Firefox: the It's all text! add-in, which allows you to edit POST boxes using any editor you choose.  (I edit most of my postings here using `vim`.)

Comment: @Fiktik That's wrong.  You can initialize any aggregate this way; it certainly doesn't have to be a POD.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The inclusion of a user-defined c-tor means it's no longer an aggregate type.  This would also be the case if there was no user-defined c-tor for the `struct` itself, but you have a non-static data-member of the `struct` that is not a POD or aggregate type.

Comment: Many thnax for super-fast answers.
The code got serialize - though my question got grasped :) :)
Thanx for help again !

Comment: @Jason you mean aggregate, not POD.  Not all aggregates are POD (and vice versa in C++11).

Comment: Super-fast, but irrelevant.  Who said anything about PODs.  He's asking about aggregate initialization, which doesn't require a POD, but (surprise, surprise) and aggregate.

Comment: @JamesKanze Okay, fixed ... you're having fun with me today! :-)

Comment: How does C++11 change this? I know it does things to initializers to help with non-PODs, but does it effect aggregates, just PODs, ...?

Comment: @peachykeen uniform initializer syntax will call a constructor if one is available with the appropriate number of parameters.  It will not bypass constructors directly to initialize members.

Comment: As @ecatmur points out, in both C++11 and C++03, only aggregates can be initalized using an initializer list.  In C++11 you also can initialize a non-aggregate with an initializer list if there is a constructor that takes one of the appropriate type.  The confusion with PODs is that in C++03 all PODs are aggregates, but in C++11 not all PODs are aggregates.  In C++11 you can have a non-copy, non-default constructor and still be a PODs, but not an aggregate.

Comment: @Jason Having fun with everyone:-).  But in this case, the difference is important.  It's very frequent (for me, at least) to have `struct` with `std::string` members, and to use aggregate initialization.

Comment: @Jason
"In C++11 you can have a non-copy, non-default constructor and still be
a PODs, but not an aggregate."
I don't think so.  In §9/10: "POD struct109 is a non-union class that is
both a trivial class and a standard-layout class".  A trivial class must
have a trivial default constructor, and a class with any user defined
constructor can never have a trivial default constructor.
To be trivial, the default constructor must be generated by the
compiler, and the compiler will not generate one if there is any user
defined constructor.

Comment: @JamesKanze What about Section 12.1/5?  It seems like it's saying you can have a user-defined constructor and still have a trivial default constructor ... Did I miss something?

Comment: @Jason A user defined constructor is never trivial.  And the second
sentence in §12.1/5 is "If there is **no** user-declared 
constructor for class X, a constructor having no parameters is
implicitly declared as defaulted."  (Emphesis added.)  If there is any
user defined constructor, the only way you can have a default
constructor is to define one yourself, which automatically makes it
non-trivial.  (But perhaps declaring `MyClass() default;` results in a
trivial default constructor, even with other user defined constructors.
I've not thought about this.)

Comment: @JamesKanze Okay, the `MyClass() = default;` example was what I was thinking of as the reason you can have user-defined non-copy, non-default constructors and still be a PODs, but not an aggregate, in C++11

Answer (score 4):

Because the language specifies it that way...

The reason is that the constructor is the designated way to initialize the object to a valid state, so just dumping values into fields directly makes no sense.The ideas is that you either have a collection of values, or a self contained object but what you want to do would make it a little of both.

Answer (score 3):

Only aggregates may be initialized with an initializer list.  Per 8.5.1:1, the inclusion of a user-provided constructor prevents a struct or class from being an aggregate:

> [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11)
>
> #### 8.5.1 Aggregates [dcl.init.aggr]
>
> 1 - An aggregate is an array or a class (Clause 9) with no user-provided constructors [...]

In C++03,

> [c++03](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b03)
>
> #### 8.5.1 - Aggregates [dcl.init.aggr]
>
> 1 - An aggregate is an array or a class (clause class) with no user-declared constructors [...]

Aggregates are distinct from PODs ([c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) 9:10); not all aggregates are POD and not all PODs are aggregates; a class with a user-provided destructor could be an aggregate but not a POD, while a class with a non-copy non-default constructor could be POD but not an aggregate.

Demonstration:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

struct non_pod_aggregate { int i, j; ~non_pod_aggregate() {} };
struct non_aggregate_pod { int i, j; non_aggregate_pod(int) {}
    non_aggregate_pod() = default; };

int main() {
    std::cout << std::is_pod<non_pod_aggregate>::value << '\n'; // false
    std::cout << std::is_pod<non_aggregate_pod>::value << '\n'; // true
    non_pod_aggregate{0, 0};
    // non_aggregate_pod{0, 0}; // does not compile
}
```

In C++03, all PODs ([c++03](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b03) 9:4) are aggregates, but it is still possible to have aggregates that are not PODs; as above, a user-provided destructor is enough to disqualify a struct from being POD.

Comment: Keep in mind he's using a pretty old version of gcc, so it's going to be C++03 and not C++11 ... C++11 has relaxed the rules a bit on what is considered a POD-type and what is not when it comes to constructors.

Comment: Section 9/4 of the C++03 standard states: "*A POD-struct is an aggregate class that has no non-static data members of type non-POD-struct, non-POD-union (or array of such types) or reference, and has no user-defined copy assignment operator and no user-defined destructor.*" ... So in order to be an aggregate type, the POD-struct can't have a user-declared constructor of any type, and that includes a non-copy non-default constructor.

Comment: @Jason this is aggregate initialization, so the POD rules are not completely relevant.

Answer (score 1):

In C++03 list-initialization only works for aggregates. You need to change your code to call the constructor:

```
myStruct ms;
```

If you want to be able to specify values for all of the members, you need to add a constructor taking enough arguments:

```
struct myStruct
{
    int a;
    double b;

    myStruct() : a(), b() { }
    myStruct(int a, double b) : a(a), b(b) { }
};

void main()
{
    myStruct ms(7, 7.7);
}
```